# how to transmit ibeacon and scan ibeacon at the same time using altbeacon library?

Tags: ibeacon, altbeacon

I want to enable an mobile phone to transmit ibeacon and scan ibeancon at the same time using altbeacon API.  What is the suitable value for AdvertiseMode, ForegroundBetweenScanPeriod and ForegroundScanPeriod. Besides these three parameters, is there any other issue I need to take into account?
    Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The default values for these parameters will work fine (foreground scan period of 1100ms, between scan period of 0, and AdvertiseMode LOW_LATENCY.)

It is important to note that an Android device that transmits will not be able to scab its own transmissions.  You must have a second device to do this.